# THE (A) strategy of paying everyone the same salary

Tags: grammar

I was discussing a topic from IELTS writing test with anoter person. The topic sounded something like this “Should a company pay everyone the same salary?”.

I said, “A company could go bankrupt after implementing **THE** strategy of paying everyone the same salary”.

He corrected me, “A company could go bankrupt after implementing **A** strategy of paying everyone the same salary”.

I understand that in many cases we should use "a strategy": "A new business strategy" or "A new marketing strategy", but
I used "the" because I thought that "paying everyone the same salary" can be considered as a specific strategy.

Am I wrong?

Comment: As a native British English speaker I can tell you that idiomatically you are wrong, it would definitely be "a" strategy. But I have no logical/grammatical explanation for that (I agree that "the" would appear to be correct!) so I can't write a proper answer.

Comment: Certainly if someone gave a list of available strategies, you would use "the". "*I will implement the strategy of paying everyone the same*" would work idiomatically if it followed the question: "*There are three strategies available: You can pay dependant on age, you can pay dependant on years with the company, or you can pay everyone the same salary. Which will you choose?*"

Comment: @AndyT As a native British English speaker I can tell you that the use of either 'the' or 'a' here is quite acceptable.

Comment: @AndyT As another native British English speaker, in response to "_Should a company pay everyone the same salary?_" you could definitely use either, and I'd probably favour "_the_" since that specific strategy is mentioned in the question. If the question was something like "_Choose a wage strategy and discuss its merits_" then you would write "_A strategy of..._". If you were writing an essay/blog _in isolation_ then the answer would be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either one can be used.  The distinction is whether there is effectively only one such strategy ("the"), or instead there is a "menu" of options to meet the criterion ("a").

Comment: I daresay the situation is squishier than that. Even if there's only one such strategy, it has to be introduced (with "a" or "some") if it's not well-known enough. And if it is, it probably has a name that should be used.

Comment: The strategy is introduced in the question, so a response to the question could legitimately use "_the_" (a standalone essay/blog would be different).